# SoundCloud API - can't get past 2nd page of results using linked_partitioning

Tags: c#, soundcloud

Hi there I have recently switched from using an offset to linked_partitioning to get paginated results from the SoundCloud API as detailed here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated

The issue I have is that when I get to the second page of results, the next_href value is exactly the same as the url used to get the second page of results, hence I can never get past the second page.

Here is the code I am using:

```
this.feedItemRootObject = await this.soundCloudRequester.GetFeedItems(TracksToLoadUrl, roamingSettings.Values["access_token"].ToString());

    if (this.feedItemRootObject != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.feedItemRootObject.LoadMoreUrl))
        {
            TracksToLoadUrl = this.feedItemRootObject.LoadMoreUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            this.HasMoreItems = false;
        }

        bindableTracks = await TrackConverter.ConvertToListOfFeedItems(this.feedItemRootObject);
    }
    else
    {
        this.HasMoreItems = false;
        return null;
    }
```

and the original URL I am using is https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?limit=20&linked_partitioning=1&oauth_token=

Any help is much appreciated!